# When is the generic fibre geometrically irreducible?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, arithmetic-geometry

Let $X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes. According to Exercise 6.15 in [Görtz—Wedhorn](https://web%C3%A9ducation.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Ulrich-Gortz-Torsten-Wedhorn-auth.-Algebraic-Geometry-I_-Schemes-With-Examples-and-Exercises-ViewegTeubner-Verlag-2010.pdf), if Y is integral with generic point $\eta$, then the generic fibre $X_{\eta}$ is irreducible provided that $X$ is irreducible. My questions are as follows:

1. Can someone please supply a proof of the above fact?
2. If X is a scheme over $\mathbf{Q}$ that is geometrically irreducible, would it follow from the above exercise that $X_{\eta}$ is also geometrically irreducible?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is not correct as stated. Consider the closed immersion of the origin in to $\Bbb A^1_k$ for a field $k$: $X$ is irreducible, but the generic fiber is empty and an irreducible space is nonempty.

Comment: 1. Replacing $Y$ by an open affine subset $U$ and covering $X_U$ with open affines, you are reduced to showing this when $X={\rm Spec}(B)$ and $Y={\rm Spec}(A)$. You may also assume that $X$ is integral and that the morphism is dominant (otherwise $X_\eta=\emptyset$). You then get an injective map of domains $A\to B$. If $K={\rm Frac}(A)$, you then have to prove that $B\otimes_A K$ is domain. But $B\otimes_A K$ is isomorphic to the localisation of $B$ at the image of $A\backslash 0$ in $B$, which is a domain, since $B$ is a domain.

Comment: 2. No. Consider an elliptic curve $E$ over $\bf Q$ and the multiplication by $2$ morphism $\phi$ from $E$ to $E$. Then the generic fibre of $\phi$ is the spectrum of a finite field extension of the function field $K$ of $E$ (and so is irreducible), but it is not geometrically irreducible, because over $\bar K$, it has ${\rm deg}(\phi)$ points.

Comment: @DamianRössler thanks a lot for your answers. Regarding my second question, are there additional hypothesis on $X$ and $f$ under which $X_{\eta}$ might be geometrically irreducible?

Comment: You could use Stein factorisation (Cor. 11.5 in Hartshorne). If $h^0(X_\eta,O_{X_\eta})=1$ and $f$ is smooth and proper, then this will hold. But this is of course quite restrictive.